# how to fill value in a cell based on values present in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image: Click the image]

As from the image, i wanted to know how to fill polarity(in Ratings) from polarity given in J column.
and the ratings will be like for

```
P+=5
P=4
NEU=3
N=2
N+=1
```

Polarity    Polarity(Ratings)
P
P+
P
P
P
P
P
P
P
P+
P+
P
P
NEU 
P
N
P
P
P
P
P
P
P
P
NEU 
P
P
P
P+
P
N+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a formula with nested `IF`s can do it, always think of using `MATCH` where appropriate, such as where you have an enumeration like this one. It yields simpler and better readable formulas that are extensible more easily.

```
=MATCH(TRIM(J2), {"N+","N","NEU","P","P+"},0)
```

The `0` parameter specifies an exact match.

The returned value will be the "position" of the match in the array, or `#NA` if not found.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will do the trick. I´m assuming your table begins in `A1`, if it doesn´t you´ll just have to adjust the references.

**Step 1:** write the following in the first cell under Polarity(Ratings):

```
=IF(A2="P+";5;IF(A2="P";4;IF(A2="NEU";3;IF(A2="N";2;IF(A2="N+";1;0)))))
```

**Step 2:** Place your cursor on the bottom right corner of such cell(the cursor has to change from a thick maybe white cross to a thinner maybe black one) and click and drag all the way down to the last row of your table, thus copying the formula for each row and automatically changing the reference, i.e: `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, etc.

**Remember**: if your table does not begin on cell `A1` you will first have to change `A2` for whichever cell is the first under column `Polarity` and then apply the procedure.

`IF` explained:

The `IF` formula needs 3 arguments: `LOGIC_TEST`, `RETURN_VALUE_IF_TRUE`, `RETURN_VALUE_IF_FALSE`

`LOGIC_TEST`: a condition which returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE` values, ex: `A2="P+"`
`RETURN_VALUE_IF_TRUE`: value to output in cell if `LOGIC_TEST` is `TRUE`, ex: `1`.
`RETURN_VALUE_IF_FALSE`: value to output in cell if `LOGIC_TEST` is `FALSE`, ex: `0`.

By nesting this formula as many times as needed you can simulate a recursive behavior which will eventually output the corresponding number.